# Sass and Compass weird css errors after install

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, precompiler, scout-sass

I installed compass and I can't compile to css properly. I have no idea what's causing it. Even thou stackoverflow is asking me to write more.

1. Installed scout.
2. Created simple css and html file.
3. Tried to compile css file.
4. Got error.
5. Could not find an answer on google.

---

My css:

```
body {
    background: black;
}
```

Output:

```
/*
Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "black": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";"
        on line 2 of C:/Users/Andrej/Documents/My Dropbox/Web Projects/First good website/sass/main.sass

1: C:/Users/Andrej/Documents/My Dropbox/Web Projects/First good website/sass/main.sass

Backtrace:
C:/Users/Andrej/Documents/My Dropbox/Web Projects/First good website/sass/main.sass:2
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/scss/parser.rb:1129:in `expected'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/script/lexer.rb:199:in `expected!'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/script/parser.rb:486:in `assert_done'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/script/parser.rb:50:in `parse'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/script/parser.rb:166:in `parse'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/script.rb:31:in `parse'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/engine.rb:875:in `parse_script'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/engine.rb:608:in `parse_property'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/engine.rb:597:in `parse_property_or_rule'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/engine.rb:578:in `parse_line'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/engine.rb:471:in `build_tree'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/engine.rb:490:in `append_children'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1603:in `each'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/engine.rb:489:in `append_children'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/engine.rb:480:in `build_tree'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1603:in `each'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/engine.rb:473:in `build_tree'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/engine.rb:490:in `append_children'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1603:in `each'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/engine.rb:489:in `append_children'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/engine.rb:345:in `_to_tree'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/engine.rb:315:in `_render'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/../sass/engine.rb:262:in `render'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:140:in `compile'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:126:in `timed'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:139:in `compile'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/logger.rb:45:in `red'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:138:in `compile'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:118:in `compile_if_required'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:103:in `run'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1603:in `each'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:101:in `run'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:126:in `timed'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:100:in `run'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/watch_project.rb:147:in `recompile'
org/jruby/RubyMethod.java:133:in `call'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:268:in `call'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:228:in `call'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/path.rb:73:in `run_callback'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/path.rb:55:in `callback_action'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/path.rb:35:in `update'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/state/directory.rb:39:in `modified'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1603:in `each'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/state/directory.rb:37:in `modified'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/state/directory.rb:18:in `refresh'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/backends/polling.rb:17:in `run'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1603:in `each'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/backends/polling.rb:17:in `run'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1419:in `loop'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/backends/polling.rb:15:in `run'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm/monitor.rb:26:in `run'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib/fssm.rb:70:in `monitor'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/watch_project.rb:87:in `perform'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/base.rb:18:in `execute'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:19:in `execute'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:43:in `perform!'
d:/program files (x86)/scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!'
d:\program files (x86)\scout\bin\compass:12:in `(root)'
*/
body:before {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
  content: "Syntax error: Invalid CSS after \"black\": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was \";\"\A         on line 2 of C:/Users/Andrej/Documents/My Dropbox/Web Projects/First good website/sass/main.sass\A \A 1: C:/Users/Andrej/Documents/My Dropbox/Web Projects/First good website/sass/main.sass"; }
```

Please help and thanks for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem might be that you're writing a `.sass` file, you probably want to be writing a `.scss` file. `.sass` is the older version of the syntax that isn't compatible with regular CSS.

Comment: Worked! Great :) thanks for the fast answer. I will accept it when stackoverflow let's me.

Comment: To Nathan Bouscal: by "`.sass` isn't compatible with regular CSS" you probably meant that CSS is syntactically a subset of SCSS. SASS is older and one can't turn `.css` into `.sass` just by renaming, but the indented SASS syntax is fully supported and compatible. I prefer SASS because it's much cleaner, much more readable and much quicker to write. SCSS just adds a lot of noise: http://d.pr/i/7sbD+ (though SCSS does allow some nice code alignment not possible with SASS).

Comment: @lolmaus Yes, that is what I meant, I probably could have phrased it better: `.sass` isn't an extension of CSS.