# SASS - compile Error with px

Tags: css, sass

I don't understnad the compile error of the [code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FzHrG)
What is wrong here, how to make it the right way?

SASS

```
.box{
 width: 400px;
 height: 100px;
 background: red;

 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sass and Compass weird css errors after install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892584/sass-and-compass-weird-css-errors-after-install)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the CodePen up to use `.scss` syntax instead of `.sass` syntax.  If you do that, it works.

The `.sass` syntax is not CSS-compatible.